# How do you copy a local file while logged into a SSH session within Linux (ubuntu)?

Tags: ssh

how can i transfer a local file to a logged in ssh session without using scp? im doint this in the terminal under ubuntu, but this goes for any linux system.

** say im logged into a server via the terminal in ubuntu and now i want to copy one of my files on my desktop over to that logged in session?

Comment: `rsync` or `scp` are the only ways I know of.

Answer (score 3):

short answer: You can't. SSH is acronym for Secure Shell. To TRANSFER files, you NEED scp, which stands for Secure Copy.

**Edit:** what you CAN do, is to use ssh to transfer files without already being connected, here is how:

`cat file.name.ext | ssh login@example.com 'cat >> file.name.ext'`

Answer (score 3):

scp or mount via sshfs are the options that come to mind.

You may wish to look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/ssh-easily-copy-file-to-local-system